# how can i make my cart table work properly in postgress?

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-design

what we are trying to input are the fields and we chose to manually insert the cart_id in an atmept to use the same cart for multiple items like a store:

```
BEGIN;
INSERT INTO cart_tb(cart_id, inventory_id, desired_amount, row_status)
VALUES
(1, 1, 2, 1),
(2, 3, 1, 1),
(2, 1, 1, 1);
END;
```

basically how it should work is that i can have only 1 cart_id but multiple inventory id's (inv_id), but the combination of Inv_id and cart_id should be unique, so i can have different carts that can have same items like in real world situations.
This is my current table:

```
CREATE TABLE public.cart_tb
(
    cart_id integer NOT NULL GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY ( INCREMENT 1 START 1 MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 2147483647 CACHE 1 ),
    inventory_id integer NOT NULL,
    desired_amount integer NOT NULL,
    row_status integer NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT "cart_PK" PRIMARY KEY (cart_id),
    CONSTRAINT "cart_UK" UNIQUE (cart_id, inventory_id),
    CONSTRAINT "cart_inventory_FK" FOREIGN KEY (inventory_id)
        REFERENCES public.inventory_tb (inventory_id) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
)

TABLESPACE pg_default;

ALTER TABLE public.cart_tb
    OWNER to postgres;
```

any suggestions on how i can fix this? I keep getting a key conflict..

```
ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "cart_PK"
DETAIL:  Key (cart_id)=(2) already exists.
SQL state: 23505
```

Answer (score 0):

ok seems like you need a compound primary key , but I recommend add an id and make that one as primary key and add a unique key on  cart_id, inventory_id
:

```
CREATE TABLE public.cart_tb
(
    cart_id_pk integer NOT NULL GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY ( INCREMENT 1 START 1 MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 2147483647 CACHE 1 ),
    cart_id integer not null,
    inventory_id integer NOT NULL,
    desired_amount integer NOT NULL,
    row_status integer NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT "cart_PK" PRIMARY KEY (cart_id_pk),
    CONSTRAINT "cart_UK" UNIQUE (cart_id, inventory_id),
    CONSTRAINT "cart_inventory_FK" FOREIGN KEY (inventory_id)
        REFERENCES public.inventory_tb (inventory_id) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
```

if not you can set both cart_id, inventory_id as compound primary key:

```
CONSTRAINT "cart_PK" PRIMARY KEY (cart_id, inventory_id)
```

in that case you don't need unique key anymore .